# react-pdf is rendering with parent although useMemo

Tags: reactjs, frontend, react-pdf

I'm using `react-pdf` and the component that holds the PDF seems to render every time the parent renders. 'Loading PDF' appears every time the parent renders.

This is my component:

```
import { Document, Page } from 'react-pdf';
const PDFView = () => {
    
  return (
    <Document file={props.file}>
      <Page width={100} height={100}></Page>
    </Document>
  );
};
    
export default PDFView;
```

I used `useMemo` for the parent that holds the PDFView component, and it's working well with the other elements, only PDFView keeps rendering.

This is the parent component:

```
const DropBox = () => {
const preview ='example.png';
const type ='application/pdf';
const hasFile = true;

return (
    {hasFile && (
      type === 'application/pdf' ?
       <PDFView file= {file}></PDFView>
       :
        <img alt="" src={preview} />
     )           
    )}
  );
};
```

I used `useMemo` for Dropbox component:

```
  const MemoDropBox = useMemo(() => {
    return Dropbox();
  }, []);

  return (
     {MemoDropBox}
  )
```

Any guidance/help is appreciated.

Thanks.